# Jenkins Publish Over FTP sends dist instead of contents of this catalog

Tags: jenkins, ftp, devops

Hi I using Jenkins to deploy files (project is write in Vue.js). I'm using plugin to jenkins [Publish Over FTP](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ftp/). I run build `npm i && npm run build`, jenkns created catalog `dist` with my project. Now I need send contents of catalog `dist` to my server by FTP. This is my config to Publish Over FTP:

```
Source files: dist/**
Remote directory: /public_html/
```

FTP plugin send file to my server but in catalog `public_html` I have catalog `dist`. I need send file without catalog `dist`. I need only contents of `dist` catalog in `public_html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found resolve I add to `Remove prefix` value `dist`:

[image]